# How can i do button on hold for two second call function1 if less then two second call function2?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this button which is not working correctly for hold button for a period (but it works like click only).

Where i was trying to do if the button is `hold` for greater/equal then 2 seconds then `callfunction1`, if the button was pressed less then 2 seconds then `callfuntion2`.

```
var clickDisabled = false;

function clickLocker() {      
  /* @Button: 2 seconds */
  clickDisabled = true;
  setTimeout(function(){clickDisabled = false;}, 2000);      
}

function callfunction1() { // you have hold he button for greater then or equal 2 second } 
function callfunction2() { // you have hold the button less then 2 second } 

$('.button').live("click",function()
{ 
  if (clickDisabled) {
    alert("locked for 2 second");
    return;
  }
  clickLocker();
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to measure the time difference between `mousedown` and `mouseup` events then decide which function to call?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That was a great suggestion from slash. This is how you can do this

```
var clickstart;
var clickstop;
$("a").on('mousedown', function(e) {    
    clickstart = e.timeStamp;
}).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    clickstop = e.timeStamp- clickstart
    if(clickstop >= 2000) two()
    else one();
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/5XADH/2/)

---

#### Updates:

It might be necessary to track the mouse movement like @MarkRhodes wrote in his comments. So for that, check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/5XADH/3/) update

Comment: Only a minor point, but do you need to check whether the user moves the mouse to a different element between the mouse going down then, up?  If the user presses the mouse down on one element then up on another, with a 2 second gap in between, you might be calling `two` when you mean to call `one.

Answer (score 2):

I think this solution should work. I have not tested it but it should give you the right idea.

```
var startTime;

function callfunction1() { // you have hold he button for greater then or equal 2 second } 
function callfunction2() { // you have hold the button less then 2 second } 

function buttonDownEvent() { 
  var Time = new Date();
  startTime = Time.getTime();
}

function buttonUpEvent() { 
  if(new Date().getTime() - startTime < 2000)
    callfunction2()
  else
    callfunction1()
}

$('.button').live("mousedown",function()
{ 
  buttonDownEvent();
});

$('.button').live("mouseup",function()
{ 
  buttonUpEvent();
});
```

Comment: Seems this had already been answered, and with nicer solutions than mine too!

Comment: I like this solution. Easy to use without jQuery since you dont use the (e) argument. I use it with the OnMouseDown and OnMouseUp events.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for both events, mousedown and mouseup, measuring the time between both:

```
     var timeDown;
     var timeUp;
     $('.button').live("mousedown",function(){
            timeDown = event.timeStamp;
     });
     $('.button').live("mouseup",function(){
            timeUp = event.timeStamp;
            time = timeUp-timeDown;
            if (time>2000){
                function1();
            }else{
                function2();
            }


     });
```

please note that event.timeStamp wont work well in firefox. For firefox you can do (new Date).getTime();

Comment: It should be noted that as of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers.

Comment: @Th0rndike: mouse down is working showing timeDown value. But when i do mouse up its not showing anything it shows still mousedown value only.

Comment: My answer is freakishly identical to yours LOL

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using events to the mouseup and mousedown events and timing the difference between them.  Also, you need to remember which element caused the click - if the user released the mouse on a different element then it should just do the "non 2-second hold" function.  A JSFiddle showing this working is available here: http://jsfiddle.net/35rw3/6/.

Comment: You dont need to use Date class for timestamp, jquery's event objects, keeps the track of time.

Comment: Why did you removed your comments? It was a good suggestion. Check my answer.

Comment: I just didn't check whether it was actually needed before commenting!  I'll put the comment back so you answer makes more sense!