# Button hold down function for links

Tags: javascript, html

I need help: I'm trying to make a javascript (with not much luck so far).

There are buttons on the page I generate with php, they should work as follows:

If I click the button for less than whatever seconds the link opens like if the button has: onClick="self.location='url'".
Else the button is held down for more than whatever seconds the link should open in a new tab like if the button had: onclick="window.open('url');"

It would be great if it could work for links also.

It's probably easy to do, but I have no js knowledge at all and I'm flooded with other stuff I actually know how to do so that is why I ask for Your help. I have already missed my deadline. :(

My goal is to make a php function to create buttons:
like : createbutton($name,$link,$class,$delay, ...  );
But don't worry about that, I can do that.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868319/how-can-i-do-button-on-hold-for-two-second-call-function1-if-less-then-two-secon

Comment: It'd be possible to do this by catching "mousedown" and "mouseup" events, but I recommend reconsidering this plan. The web doesn't work this way; nobody will understand your interface.

Answer (score 0):

An Example here

```
var counter= 0;
doCount=function(){
setTimeout(function(){
counter++;
},1000);
}
doFunc=function(){
if(counter>2){ 
//do something if delay is greater than 2 second
}
else{
//do something if delay is less than 2 second
}
}

document.getElementById('myBtn').mousedown = doCount;
document.getElementById('myBtn').mouseup = doFunc;
```

Try this code

Comment: Thank You for the script, could You help me make the script this way:
The script would be in the header then on the element i would specify: onclick= "ourfuncion('http://whatever.com');"
Then it would open the page in the same tab if less then 2 sec, and in a new tab if it over 2secs. If I got this right the element could be also an image or link, am i?